# i am getting error after trying to extend user model using one to one link

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

error i am receiving
IntegrityError at /washer/
my code
code inside my models.py

```
class washers(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile=models.IntegerField()
    added_by=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_washers(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.washers.save()
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_washers(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        washers.objects.create(user=instance)
```

code inside views.py

```
def wash(request):
    wf=washerform()
    uf=Userform()
    if request.method=="POST":
        uf=Userform(data=request.POST)
        wf=washerform(data=request.POST)
        if uf.is_valid() and wf.is_valid():
            uf.save()
            wf.save()
            return HttpResponse("suscess fully crated ")
    return render(request,'webpage/washer.html',{'fm':wf,'uf':uf})
```

Comment: It means you did not log in, so `request.user` is not a `User` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you did not log in, so `request.user` is not a `User` object. You need to enforce that only people who are logged in can see and update the page. You can do this with a [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def wash(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = Userform(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        wf = washerform(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.washers)
        if uf.is_valid() and wf.is_valid():
            uf.save()
            wf.save()
            return HttpResponse("suscess fully crated ")
    else:
        wf = washerform()
        uf=Userform()
    return render(request,'webpage/washer.html', {'fm':wf,'uf':uf})
```

or if you want to *register* a `washers`, you should *remove* the signal that creates a `washer` and work with:

```
# remove the signal that creates a washers object.

def wash(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = Userform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        wf = washerform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if uf.is_valid() and wf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save()
            wf.instance.user = user
            wf.save()
            return HttpResponse("suscess fully crated ")
    else:
        wf = washerform()
        uf=Userform()
    return render(request,'webpage/washer.html', {'fm':wf,'uf':uf})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: I am using view method  wash for signup how then i should use decorator @login_required

Comment: @JAYESHrathi: if you are using it for signup, then of course `request.user` is not a `User`, and therefore `request.user.washers` does not make much sense either.

Comment: after removing now getting error IntegrityError at /washer/

Comment: @JAYESHrathi: of course, since your signal creates a `washers` record, and the form tries to create one as well. This is one of the *many* many reasons *not* to use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: how in your  post # remove the signal that creates a washers object.  user = uf.save() returning object because i read uf.save()  return NONE but in this case i am getting object how. @willem-van-onsem

Comment: @JAYESHrathi: you remove the `create_user_washers` method in the model...

Comment: @JAYESHrathi: where do you read that. `.save()`ing a *model* is not the same as saving a *form*.